# How to use General Additive Model to impute missing data?

Tags: missing-data, generalized-additive-model, data-imputation, information-extraction

I am new to GAMs and R.

I have a long lists of time series of different lengths. Many of them are incomplete.
I have fitted a GAM and use the predict.gam function(mgcv package in R) to each time series with the hope to impute the response variables for years without records (NA).
Nonetheless, when I run the code predict(gamobject, type = "response"). I am only able to obtain predicted values for the non NA records.

I am  trying to follow Spooner at al. (2018)to impute data. Here is the code she is using: https://github.com/spoonerf/LPI_rapid_warming/blob/master/LPI_rapid_warming_code.Rmd
Nonetheless, I am using a different dataset.

Is there any way to extract the fitted values of the response variable from a GAM?

I hope I have made clear my problem and thank you in advance for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

As is standard for models fitted in R, if you don't pass anything to the `newdata` argument of `predict()`, you get back fitted values for the observations to which the model was fitted.

Assuming the `df` is the data frame containing your data and passed to the `data` argument of `gam()`, then you should do:

```r
predict(gamobject, newdata = df)
```

to get predicted values for all of the observations in `df`.

Comment: I truly appreciate it, Gavin Simpson. I was avoiding to use newdata = df because I was getting error messages. Finally, I realised I needed to create a year vector instead of using the year column from the original data set. Somehow that solved my problem and I could use df and extract all the fitted values needed. I do not know the reason behind but it worked.